# Can't SSH into my Bitbucket repository - conq: repository access denied

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have followed a million guides regarding this and I cannot get it to work. Earlier, I successfully pushed via SSH to my private Bitbucket git repository, now suddenly it wont work.

I have recreated the keys with a new passphrase, added it to my Bitbucket settings and it wont work.

Okay, here are the steps I took:

1. Deleted old key pair (project1 and project1.pub)
2. Recreated it with this command `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/project1 -C "project1"`
3. Created a `config` in `~/.ssh` file for my **two** Bitbucket accounts, with the following contents:

`Host project1
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project1
Host project2
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project2`

4. Grabbed the contents of `project1.pub` and created a new SSH key entry in my Bitbucket account.
5. Added `ssh-agent` in my `~/.zshrc` plugin list like this: `plugins=(git ssh-agent)` and restarted Terminal
6. Did `ssh-add -l` and saw only `project2` was loaded
7. Did `ssh-add ~/.ssh/project1`, entered my passphrase and success, like this:

`2048 SHA256:THESHA256 /Users/myuser/.ssh/project2 (RSA)
2048 SHA256:THESHA256 /Users/myuser/.ssh/project1 (RSA)`

8. Restarted Terminal and did `ssh-add -l` and it listed both entries
9. Went to my project and did `git push` and it told me I had no access.

---

When I do `ssh -T git@bitbucket.com`, it tells me I'm logged in with the username of **project2**.

> logged in as project2_user.

My system is **OS X 10.11.5**

I could never fix multiple identities on my computer and always used HTTPS, but I need to make everything more secure with SSH, which also allows my account to have two-factor authentication. Therefore using SSH is a must now and I don't know what to do.

P.S: I did the creating steps for the identity for **project2** too, but I'm fairly certain that it doesn't work either.

---

Guide I followed:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html

---

**EDIT**

**project2** has no passphrase, while **project1** does! Just thought maybe this is relevant.

**EDIT 2**

I did `ssh-add -D` to remove all loaded keys, then added the key for **project1**, entered passphrase and pushed. It worked. But now my other identity is not working because its key is not loaded.

Why aren't my multiple identities working?

Comment: What does `git config --get remote.origin.url` output for both projects?

Answer (score 0):

If different repositories on the same remote host require usage of different SSH identities then you must use SSH aliases.

Check that `remote.origin.url` has the following (or equivalent) values in your local repositories:

- **project1**: `git@bitbucket.org:accountX/project1.git`
- **project2**: `git@bitbucket.org:accountY/project2.git`

`accountX` may be either your account associated with your 1st identity on Bitbucket (i.e. `project1_user`), or another account that has granted access to `project1_user` to their repository `project1`. The same goes for `project2`.

Now, when git has to connect to the remote repository from your local repository, it will first have to connect to the remote server, and the latter for your both projects is set to `bitbucket.org`. Then, how does git know which SSH identity to use? It picks *some* identity associated with `bitbucket.org`.

Update your `remote.origin.url` settings as follows:

- **project1**: `git@project1:accountX/project1.git`
- **project2**: `git@project2:accountY/project2.git`

Then, when git is told to connect to `git@project1`, it resolves `project1` to the corresponding entry in `~/.ssh/config` and uses the identity specified therein. Similarly for `project2`.

Comment: The repos in Bitbucket are stored in "Teams". So **project1**'s `git config --get remote.origin.url` is `git@bitbucket.org:team/project1.git` and the same goes for **project2**. The repo paths are set correctly. Did you read **Edit 2**?

Comment: My answer equally applies to the "Teams" case, too. Yet, I updated it.

Comment: Can you try `git clone project1:accountX/project1.git` and `git clone project2:accountY/project2.git`?

Answer (score -2):

Basing on my experience you can save yourself lot of time and efforts using HTTPS in this circumstance.

I'd not success with multiple SSH identities few months ago.